# Initial values in forms elements

Tags: 8, forms

When I create a form (using [form api](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api)) I need, sometimes, to assign a default value to form elements, or to create a list for `select` elements, under certains conditions. In this cases, I need to do some queries, process, etc. I do it in `buildForm` method, but I was wondering if It is the right way because this method is called again if I need to rebuild the form due to ajax change (for example with dependant fields).
Until now, I manage it checking `$form_state` variable for some field in order to see if a field is empty or not, but is it the right way to do it? is there another method to initialize the form elements?

Comment: Yes, `buildForm` is the correct place to do that, and `$form_state` is the correct variable to check for the current state of the form in order to make decisions about which elements to show/hide

Comment: Yes $form_state->getValue is good or if entity $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()

Comment: Ok. Thanks you. I'll continue doing it the same way, but I think It's a little weird.